# Visual Studio 2008 debugging issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I'm working in VS 2008 and have three projects in one solution.  I'm debugging by attaching to a .net process invoked by a third party app (SalesLogix, a CRM app).

Once it has attached to the process and I attempt to set a breakpoint in one of the projects, it doesn't set a breakpoint in that file.  It actually switches the current tab to another file in another project and sets a breakpoint in that document.  If the file isn't open, it even goes so far as to open it for me.  I can't explain this.  I've got no clue.  Anyone seen such odd behavior?  I wouldn't believe it if I wasn't seeing it myself.

A little more info: if I set a breakpoint before attaching, it shows the "red dot" and says no symbols loaded...no problem...I expect that.  When I attach and invoke my .net code from SalesLogix and switch back to VS, my breakpoint is completely gone (not even a warning that the source doesn't match the debug file).  When I attempt to manually load the debug file, then I get a message that the symbol file does not match the module.  The .pdb and the .dll are timestamped the same, so I'm stumped.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thx,

Jeff

Comment: Is the line you're setting the breakpoint on a method/function call? Maybe the function has been inlined so VS is smart enough to set the breakpoint in the method itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw this functionality in older versions of VS.Net (2003 I think).  It may still exist in current versions, but I haven't encountered it.  Seems that files with the same name, even in different directories confuse VS.Net, and it ends up setting a break point in a file with the same name.  May only happen if the classes in the file both have the same name also.  So much for namespaces I guess.

You also may want to check your build configuration to make sure that all the projects are in fact building in debug mode.  I know I've been caught a couple times when the configuration got changed somehow for the solution, and some projects weren't compiling in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Kibbee, you were right!  It was two files with the same name in different folders.  I was setting the breakpoint in the correct file on line 58 - it was putting the breakpoint on the other file at line 58.  I was finally able to set a breakpoint by using the "Debug-->New Breakpoint-->Break at Function Name" menu option and entering my function name.  It stopped exactly like it should have then.

I agree - so much for namespaces, right?  Damn thing cost me a couple of hours. Oh, well...at least it's solved and I know why.

Thx for the answer and thx to Matt for his reply, too!